# using variable defined outside Awk

Tags: linux, shell, awk, scripting

I have codded the following lines :

```
ARRAY=($(awk 'FS = ";" {print $3}' file.txt))

LINE_CREATOR=`echo "aaaa;bbbb;cccccccc" |

'{awk -F";"};

END

 for (i in ARRAY)
         {

         print $'${ARRAY['i']}'

         }

}'`
```

the File.txt looks like

```html
1;8;3
4;6;1
7;9;2
```

Explanation :

the array contains the value : 3 1 2

so the loop will loop on the array , and extract fields $3 $1 $2 from the "aaaa;bbbb;cccccccc" using awk

and  the final output should be this

```html
ccccccccaaaabbbb
```

I still have some errors while launching my script.

Comment: and what about the logic? Why "aaaa;bbbb;cc..." becomes this?

Comment: There's not really any nice way of passing an array to awk (which seems to be what you're trying to do). I'd suggest running your script like `echo foo | awk '...' file.txt -`, to process the file and standard input at the same time.

Comment: Please explain what is the logic you want to achieve and also paste the errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making a few guesses here but I think that this does what you want:

```
$ echo "aaaa;bbbb;cccccccc" | awk -F\; 'NR == FNR { n = split($0, a); next } 
{ printf "%s", a[$3] } END { print "" }' - file
ccccccccaaaabbbb
```

`NR == FNR` means that the block is only run for the first input. `-` as an argument tells awk to read first from standard input. The string is split on `FS` (`;`) into the array `a`. `next` skips the rest of the script.

The second block is only run for the second input (the text file). The values in the third field are used to print the elements in the array `a`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass the index as an `awk` variable, here is another way

```
$  awk -F';' -v ix="$(cut -d\; -f3 file | paste -sd\;)" '
           BEGIN{n=split(ix,a)} 
                {for(i=1;i<n;i++) printf "%s",$a[i]; 
                 printf "%s\n",$a[n]}' <<< "aaaa;bbbb;cccccccc"

ccccccccaaaabbbb
```